# ¿Trabajar con mediaqueries o cambiar html?

Tags: css

Vendi un sistema en php con html y el cliente quiere verlo mas comodamente en su celular.
Tengo un template de la siguiente manera:

```html
<nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">ABM</a>
    <ul class="submenu" id="a">
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=index">Clientes</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=articulo&action=index">Articulos</a></li>

        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=proveedor&action=index">Proveedores</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=envase&action=todos">Envases</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=medida&action=index">Medidas</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=canilla&action=index">Canillas</a></li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=user&action=index">Usuarios</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Nuevo comprobante</a>
    <ul class="submenu"  id="b">
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=ticket&action=index">Ticket</a></li>
   <li ><a href="index.php?controller=facturaa&action=index">Factura</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Estado de cajas</a>
      <ul class="submenu" id="c">
        <li><a href="">Chequera</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=caja&action=gasto">Nuevo Gasto</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=caja&action=index">Cerrar caja</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=cuenta">Cuenta Corriente</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=caja&action=indexgrande">Caja Grande</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Posnet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Nueva Venta</a>
    <ul class="submenu" id="E">
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index">Canilla</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=venta&action=cerrado">Producto</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Compra de stock</a>
    <ul class="submenu" id="D">
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=stock&action=index">Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=stock&action=indexb">Barril</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?controller=stock&action=canilla">Cambio de canilla</a></li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Pero al abrir en un celular aparece asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es si usar mediaqueries de acuerdo a la resolucion standar, un j7 por ejemplo de 1280x720 me va a servir.
De ser que si, que debo hacer:aumentar el height del menu y se ajustara una opcion debajo de la otra?
Es algo nuevo para mi..

Edito y agrego el css del menu:

```css
.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
    margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
     
    width:100%;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
 background: gray;
 list-style: none;

font-size: 14px;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
 float: left;
  
 position: relative;
 width:20%;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
 background: #30A6E6;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 display: block;
 font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
 -o-transition: all .25s ease;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}
.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
 background: #000000;
}
.submenu {

 opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;

 visibility: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
li:hover ul.submenu {
 opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;

}
.submenu li {
    
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.submenu a:hover {
 background: #DF4B05;
}
.submenu a {
 background-color:#000000;
}
```

Deberia usar el height en esos elementos?

Comment: Te recomiendo implementar https://getbootstrap.com/ para resolver el problema no es mas

Comment: Es que uso bootstrap.. Pero tiene alguna herramienta para este problema?

Comment: las regillas de bootstrap deberia solucionar este problema

Comment: Si usas Bootstrap seria bueno que muestres mas código, ya que solo muestras parte del nav, y el problema también podría estar en las demás etiquetas del body.

Comment: Por otro lado, lo que muestras es como se ve en un celular. En otro celular o tablet puede verse diferente. Con el sistema de grilla de bootstrap tenes 4 puntos de corte donde podes adaptar como se ve la pantalla, en el mejor de los casos con cambios mínimos en css.

Comment: muchas gracias estuve averiguando un poco y encerre con la linea: <div class="container-fluid"> todo el menu pero el caso es que es una sola fila. Teoricamente podria mostrar un menu abajo de otro para que se vea mas grande?

Comment: Probe con un grand prime y se ve mas arrimado digamos.. Pero no todo dentro de la pantalla. Ademas de crear un container fluid.. Las columnas deben tener los 4 puntos de ancho asignado?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que estuve observando, te faltó agregar entre las cabeceras `<head></head>` la etiqueta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

No es obligatorio utilizar «user-scalable=no». Si deseas darle al usuario libertad de aplicar *zoom* puedes escribir:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Donde la escala inicial es 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo..lo implementare. El caso es que uso un celular nuevo con mucha resolucion, un HUAWEI mate 20 lite, quizas deberia probar con uno mas viejo a ver si se adpata.